# How to write to registers over i2c in u-boot

Tags: ethernet, i2c, u-boot, microchip

I am a hardware guy with little embedded systems experience, so my question may be trivial.

I need to put an Ethernet switch in "test mode 1" which is an Ethernet compliance test mode you can put the chip in for characterizing signals on a scope. at the bottom is the datasheet page that shows this register and how to put it in test mode 1.

I am using u-boot i2c commands to do this.

chip Slave address = 0x5F

Port 1 address (to be written to) = 0x1112.2 (16 bit address needs the .2, correct me if i am wrong)

I send the following command to the switch:

#i2c mw 0x05F 0x1112.2 0x01 10

Then I read it back:

#i2c md 0x05F 0x1112.2 10

1112: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 00 ............0...

The command that I am writing is only writing to the first bit. I cant for the life of me figure out how to write to any other bit at that address other than the first one. What would my u-boot i2c command look like if I wanted to set bits [15:13] to [0 0 1]?

[image: KSZ9897R datasheet page 118]

Comment: The unusual method of changing only certain bits of a control register requires the current state of the register contents.  So first read the control register.  Modify the bits of interest.  Then write that value back to the register.

Comment: @sawdust perhaps _usual_?